# Why does my DIV ovelay my text div when resized?

Tags: html, css

Few problems. It looks great when it's not re-sized. But when it's re-sized everything plays up.

Main issue is the nav; when it's resized it overlays the main text and collides with it. Also how would I go about sorting out the layout when it's resized? I want the header to always look good regardless of size.

Thank-you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    <div class="company-text"> Kidderminster Electronic Recycling</div>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#">Recycling</a>
        <a href="#">Where we collect</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="main-content">dfgf</div>
        <div class="footer">xxzxczxczxcz</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    margin: 0 0;
    height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: TCB_____;
    src: url('TCB_____.ttf');
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    height: 20%;
}

nav {

    background-color: #222;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 5%;
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}


nav a { color: #F9F9F9; display: block; float:right;  padding: 10px;  }
nav a:visited { color: #f9f9f9; }
nav a:hover { text-decoration: none; background: #27B3CF; }
nav a:active { position: relative; top: 0; }

a {
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TCB_____; /* no .ttf */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    font-size: 1.0037500100376em;
}



.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.company-text {
    font-family: TCB_____; /* no .ttf */
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 5%;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.main-content {
    background:url('all-electronics-recycling-home.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
    height: 75%;
}

.footer {
    height: 5%;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TCB_____; /* no .ttf */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**LIVE DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/48ajumza/

Comment: Your problem is that text isn't responsive, you can make it responsive though using media queries. [CSS Tricks: Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

What you need to do is scale your web browser window right down and find those problem resolutions, then you can change the font sizes etc.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz thanks for the heads up! Quick question. Personally what do you design your websites for? What screen sizes for a standard size and how many media queries? Thanks.

Comment: Well I try and design mine to be completely responsive, with seamless breakpoints. Using a framework such as Bootstrap, Foundation 5, or if you want something a little lighter, just a grid system: http://unsemantic.com/


But here are some common breakpoints for your media queries (again, from CSS Tricks, I love this site) http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

The #nav element is floated.  So, it does not have a height.  In order to give it a height, you'll need to drop something in the bottom of it that will clear floats.  I used one of your divs with the class .clear.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    <div class="company-text"> Kidderminster Electronic Recycling</div>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#">Recycling</a>
        <a href="#">Where we collect</a>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="main-content">dfgf</div>
        <div class="footer">xxzxczxczxcz</div>
    </div>
```